# Como usar o mesmo onClickListener em mais de uma View?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber o seguinte, eu tenho: `ImageButton btneditarusuario;` e um `TextView editarusuario;`, clicando em qualquer uma das duas inicia o `startActivity`.

Tem como agrupar o `ImageButton` com  o `TextView` para não ter que repetir o código?

O código:

```
editarusuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditarUsuario.class));
                }
            });

btneditarusuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditarUsuario.class));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem três possibilidades:

- Declarar uma classe que implemente a interface *View.OnClickListener*

  ```
  private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditarUsuario.class));
      }
  }
  ```

  e passá-la a cada um dos `setOnClickListener()`:

  ```
  ClickListener listener = new ClickListener();

  editarusuario.setOnClickListener(listener);
  btneditarusuario.setOnClickListener(listener);
  ```
- Fazer a Activity implementar a interface *View.OnClickListener*

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          .....
          .....

          editarusuario.setOnClickListener(this);
          btneditarusuario.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditarUsuario.class));  
      }
  }
  ```
- Usar o atributo `android:onClick=""` com o mesmo nome de método, na declaração do *ImageButton* e do *TextView*

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ....
      ....
      android:onClick="startActivityEditarUsuario" />

  <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ....
      ....
      android:onClick="startActivityEditarUsuario" />
  ```

  e declarar o método na Activity

  ```
  public void startActivityEditarUsuario(View view) {
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditarUsuario.class));  
  }
  ```